# Adding functionality - Java servlet built with Ant

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ant

I have with me a working copy of Apache FOP's Java Servlet source code.

I have compiled the code - which handles a doGet request - and deployed it on Tomcat on my localhost, and it works and its good.

**BUT** I need to add functionality for a POST method to the file.

I can do that, but I'm not sure how to use the source code. All of my experience in Java has basically been behind an IDE.

[The servlet](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/servlets.html) is built by an Ant script, build.xml, that seems to contain references to variable names. Do I need to add to this file at all? Can i just change stuff in my servlet.java, and go straight to building?

Comment: It may be useful to post the build.xml file as part of your question body to see what it's going to generate. And possibly the source for the servlet. I would expect that you should be able to simply make your changes to the source and rebuild, provided the build.xml is not doing anything particularly complex.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. If you have the source code and can build the project, then you can start a simple text editor, change the servlet Java file and then build the whole thing again.

But it will be time consuming. It can take a while until compilation problem are reported leading to high turnaround times. And you are unable to debug your code if something went wrong.

For some very small changes this approach might be suitable. But for larger changes it would be better to invest the time to configure your IDE for web application debugging.